# Identification, authentification and redirection on Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, authentication, redirect

I have a problem concerning identification, authentication and redirection on Symfony2 (v2.8.9).

I installed HWIOAuthBundle in order to use the Google Sign-in and based on a User Bundle handmade. The website is completely closed to anonymous users and you need to login to use it.

My problem is that in order to access a precise URL given by someone, and land on it after you logged in via the login page, I set in the *app/config/config.yml* the *use_referer* to *true*.

Since then, when someone goes directly to the /login page, once he's authenticated, he's taken back to the /login page instead of being re-directed on the private homepage of the website (/hub defined by the route rnd_hub_homepage). He's taken there properly identified and authenticated but I wish he shouldn't land there but on the /hub page.

If I set the line *always_use_default_target_path* to *true* in *app/config/security.yml*, then the *use_referer* is no longer taken into account for others URLs...

Here is my extract for the file *app/config/security.yml*:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        anonymous: true

    main:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        #logout: true
        logout:
            path:       /logout
            target:     /login
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                google: "/login/check-google"
            login_path: /login
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            failure_path: /login
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider
    access_control:
        - { path: ^/hub, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }
        - { path: ^/user, roles: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/XXX, roles: ROLE_XXX }
        - { path: ^/YYY, roles: ROLE_YYY }
        - { path: ^/ZZZ, roles: ROLE_ZZZ }
        - { path: ^/AAA, roles: ROLE_AAA }
        - { path: ^/BBB, roles: ROLE_BBB }
        - { path: ^/DDD, roles: ROLE_DDD }
        - { path: ^/EEE, roles: ROLE_EEE }
        - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

And here is the extract of my *app/config/config.yml* file:

```
hwi_oauth:
    firewall_names: [main]
    target_path_parameter: rnd_hub_homepage
    use_referer: true
    resource_owners:
        google:
            type:          google
#etc....
```

Thank you in advance for your various inputs on this question...
(sorry for my english, I'm french born)

Answer (score 0):

I think you have defined 2 times logout configuration. Try to remove:

```
     logout: true
```